# Test pass with Remix but fails with Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, testing, internal-transactions

I have two contracts: ElephanteumStorage and ElephanteumCore. 
Storage just keeps some data. Core is provided to change the data in the Storage.
As a constructor argument, ElephanteumCore receives Storage address so Core can call Storage's functions. Also, I have setted Core as an owner of the Storage.
  I wrote init function in Core that must save data in storage and I tested this functionality in Remix IDE with  Rinkeby and JS VM and everything was just fine.
But in Truffle test I got revert error message.

```
contract ElephanteumCore is Ownable {

        ElephanteumStorage public eStorage;

        function ElephanteumCore(address _eStorage) public payable {
            eStorage = ElephanteumStorage(_eStorage);     
        }

        function init(bytes32 _name, bytes32 _symbol, uint _supply) public onlyOwner {
            eStorage.setTotalSupply(_supply);
            eStorage.setElephantsRemainingToAssign(_supply);
            eStorage.setName(_name);
            eStorage.setSymbol(_symbol);
        }
}




contract ElephanteumStorage is Ownable {

        bytes32 public name;
        bytes32 public symbol;

        uint public totalSupply;

        uint public elephantsRemainingToAssign;

        function setName(bytes32 _name) onlyOwner external {
            name = _name;
        }

        function setSymbol(bytes32 _symbol) onlyOwner external {
            symbol = _symbol;
        }

        function setTotalSupply(uint _totalSupply) onlyOwner external {
            totalSupply = _totalSupply;
        }

        function setElephantsRemainingToAssign(uint _elephantsRemainingToAssign) onlyOwner external {
            elephantsRemainingToAssign = _elephantsRemainingToAssign;
        } 
}
```

And there is my truffle test:

```
const elephanteumCore = artifacts.require('ElephanteumCore');
const elephanteumStorage = artifacts.require('ElephanteumStorage');


contract('ElephanteumCore', accounts => {
  let eCore, eStorage;

  before(async () => {
    eStorage = await elephanteumStorage.new();
    eCore = await elephanteumCore.new(eStorage.address);
    await eStorage.transferOwnership(eCore.address);
  })

  it('Should initialize the contract correcty', async () => {
    let name = "Elephanteum";
    let symbol = "EPH";
    let supply = 100;

    await eCore.init(name, symbol, supply);

    let rName =  await eStorage.name.call();
    let rSymbol = await eStorage.symbol.call();
    let rSupply = await eStorage.totalSupply.call();

    assert.equal(name, web3.toUtf8(rName), "name should have be initialize correctly");
    assert.equal(symbol, web3.toUtf8(rSymbol), "symbol should have be initialize correctly");
    assert.equal(supply, rSupply.toNumber(), "supply should have be initialize correctly");

  })
```

I tried to run test both in testrpc and rinkeby, everywhere it raise exception on line

```
await eCore.init(name, symbol, supply);
```

And I don't know why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have deleted "build" dir and now it works. The problem was the Truffle doesn't recompile contracts before running test by default.

Answer (score 1):

You use the function `setElephantsRemainingToAssign` in the init function, but I'm not seeing that function on the `ElephanteumStorage` contract.

Comment: I have removed some functions and variables to simplify the example.
Now the example is true. As I said, I have tested the functionality in Remix. I suppose, the problem is in truffle test.